# Problem with the transition on CSS set by JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a website to learn the interaction between CSS and HTML,
but, I have a problem with this:
["page with problem"](https://circolopescalivornese.herokuapp.com/calendario_eventi.html).

The div on the right would do a transition to the bottom and this translation must be a second long, but, it's a lot faster.

I don't understand the problem.

```js
function setDescription(eventId) {
    var curEv = getEventById(eventId);

    var didascalia = document.getElementById("didascalia");
    didascalia.firstChild.data = curEv.titolo;

    var eventDescription = document.getElementById("eventDescription");
    if (eventDescription.firstChild) eventDescription.firstChild.data = curEv.descrizione;
    else eventDescription.appendChild(document.createTextNode(curEv.descrizione));

    var image = document.getElementById("imageEventImmagine");
    if (image) {
        if (image.alt === curEv.tipologia) return;
        image.src = "./resource/img/eventi/" + curEv.tipologia + ".jpg";
        image.alt = curEv.tipologia;
    } else {
        var divImmagine = document.getElementById("divImmagine");
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.id = "imageEventImmagine";
        img.src = "./resource/img/eventi/" + curEv.tipologia + ".jpg";
        img.alt = curEv.tipologia;
        divImmagine.appendChild(img);
    }
}
```

```css
.smalldesc {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .10s ease;
}

.smalldesc.expand {
    max-height:  100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="expand" class="basePreventivo smalldesc">
    <h3 id="didascalia">Seleziona un'evento</h3>
    <p id="eventDescription"></p>
    <div id="divImmagine" class="fill"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transition: all .10s ease;`

Change .10s to 1s to make the transition longer. Also

Answer (score 1):

Transition time is given .10s in CSS, change that to 1s to make it longer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that height (or max-height) can only be transitioned if it is transitioning between two literal values (no percentage or auto).

For example:

```
0px to 100px - ✅
0px to 10rem - ✅
auto to 100px - 
0px to auto - 
0px to 100% -
```

Additionally, if you want your transition to take 1 second you will need to adjust your transition timing from `0.1s` to `1s`.

To solve your animation value issues - check out this article that discusses several approaches to achieve what you need: [Using CSS Transitions on Auto Dimensions](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/)